# Erlang Cowboy running two web servers on one machine using different ports

Tags: erlang, port, cowboy

Newbie to erlang and cowboy. I am using some open source code which uses cowboy and listens to port 8080 to provide a ng-admin admin service.

I want to know if its possible for cowboy to also listen to port 80 to provide a users interface.

Any help and suggestions of where to start or any code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks,

MPC

Comment: You do not provide sufficient information to help reproduce your problem. Maybe you can include snippets of the "open source code" you are referring to or cowboy's handler, or show the erlang code that starts listening for connections. Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: I do not have a problem. My question is more about the best way to have cowboy server two different ports 80 and 8080 whith two different interfaces. Please excuse me as my terminology maybe wrong as this is all new to me. Thanks for you comment though.

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding of your question, you wan to have 2 servers running on different ports. You can call `cowboy:start_clear/3` twice, with a different port and same or different routes. It is definitely doable but as mentioned above is more recommended to use namespace routes to separate applications (like `/foo/123` and `/admin/foo/123`) instead of different ports if they use the same protocol (http in this case). In case you still need the tow servers, it will be something like:

```
    NormalRoutes = cowboy_router:compile(...),
    AdminRoutes = cowboy_router:compile(...),
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(http, [{port, 80}], #{
      env => #{dispatch => NormalRoutes}
    }),
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(http, [{port, 8080}], #{
      env => #{dispatch => AdminRoutes}
    }).
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer works well. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is whether you can start two cowboy servers in the same erlang VM. Two servers listen to two different ports. Yes you can do that. Basically you compile their own routes and bind to 8080 and 80 port when you call cowboy:start_clear.

The question is if this practice makes sense. I would suggest if you can use routes to separate two applications instead of at port level/individual web server.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to keep the two interfaces seperate so the admin remains on port 8080 as per the original open source but a new user interface layer is on port 80. Not sure if this makes sense myself. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the above example. But unfortunately as is the example did not work for me.

I kept getting service "already_started" errors. I eventually figured out that I had to provide each listener its own unique name.

```erlang
    NormalRoutes = cowboy_router:compile(...),
    AdminRoutes = cowboy_router:compile(...),
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(http_listener_name_1, [{port, 80}], #{
      env => #{dispatch => NormalRoutes}
    }),
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(http_listener_name_2, [{port, 8080}], #{
      env => #{dispatch => AdminRoutes}
    }).
```

[cowboy:start_clear(3)](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.8/manual/cowboy.start_clear/)

Hopefully that will help someone with the same problem I had.